# detect when left mouse button is down while hovering over a button in Visual Basic.net

Tags: vb.net

So I'm attempting to create a schedule grid in VB.net (exactly like the scheduler in UTorrent, if anyone is familiar) in a 24x7 layout. I want to be able to click down and drag over a series of squares to change the values of them.

I've been able to find this sample code that mostly works.

```
Private Sub DataGridView3_MouseHover(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView3.CellMouseMove
    Dim grvScreenLocation As Point = DataGridView3.PointToScreen(DataGridView3.Location)
    Dim tempX As Integer = DataGridView.MousePosition.X - grvScreenLocation.X + DataGridView3.Left
    Dim tempY As Integer = DataGridView.MousePosition.Y - grvScreenLocation.Y + DataGridView3.Top
    Dim hit As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = DataGridView3.HitTest(tempX, tempY)
    cellX = hit.RowIndex
    cellY = hit.ColumnIndex
    TextBox3.Text = cellX
    TextBox14.Text = cellY

End Sub
```

As written, this produces the desired results, however I need to have it only return cellx and celly to the text boxes only when the mouse button is down.

Comment: typically you could just use the MouseEnter event but on many controls, if the mouse button is down then the event is not fired because that combo is reserved for DragDrop operations (which only fires after a DoDragDrop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gave me what I wanted.

```
Private cellX As Integer = 0
Private cellY As Integer = 0

Private Sub DataGridView3_MouseHover(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView3.CellMouseMove

    Dim grvScreenLocation As Point = DataGridView3.PointToScreen(DataGridView3.Location)
    Dim tempX As Integer = DataGridView.MousePosition.X - grvScreenLocation.X + DataGridView3.Left
    Dim tempY As Integer = DataGridView.MousePosition.Y - grvScreenLocation.Y + DataGridView3.Top
    Dim hit As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = DataGridView3.HitTest(tempX, tempY)
    cellX = hit.RowIndex
    cellY = hit.ColumnIndex
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then

        TextBoxX.Text = cellX
        TextBoxY.Text = cellY
        DataGridView3.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).Style.BackColor = Color.Red

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished by handling mouse left button down, mouse move and mouse left button up.

When you receive a mouse left button down event on the grid, record the mouse position and set a flag. In the mouse move handler if the flag is set, highlight all cells between the initial position and the current mouse position. On receiving a mouse left button up (on the grid when the grid is set) commit the cell selection (and clear the flag).

I've used this technique successfully for a [fractal zoom](http://trelford.com/blog/post/FractalZoom.aspx).

Here's a rough outline of what you need to do:

```
Dim isSelecting As Boolean
Dim selectionStart As Point

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e)
    Dim position = e.GetPosition(Me)
    Dim hit = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(MyGrid, position)
    If hit IsNot Nothing Then
        isSelecting = True
        selectionStart = position
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(e As MouseEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)
    If isSelecting Then
        Dim position = e.GetPosition(Me)
        ' Update selection
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e)
    If isSelecting Then
        Dim position = e.GetPosition(Me)
        ' Commit selection
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code! I forgot to mention I'm a little new to VB.net so When I get home from work tonight, I'll have to sit down and figure out what all that means.  ;)

Comment: OK, so, I'm using a series of buttons placed in a grid style, not an actual grid.  I was unable to get results I wanted using a gridview. However, after creating a datagridview, i'm having an issue with OnMouseLeftButtonDown not a member of System.Windows.Form.Form and e.GetPosition is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs

Comment: Sorry you didn't specify the framework, the example is in WPF, but the principle is the same

Comment: Framework 4.5. There is a LOT in this WPF, I can't seem to find a working example.